# Why was this question about the two Underscore.js syntaxes closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I asked this question a while ago:

[What are the differences between the two Underscore.js syntaxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825182/what-are-the-differences-between-the-two-underscore-js-syntaxes)

It was closed as 'not constructive'. No one commented to say why. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 3):

No need in comments as it's written clearly in the "closed as not constructive" message:

> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, [see the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#close) for guidance.

In your case answer can be "Yes, there is difference" or "No, no difference" which boils down to Yes/No only.

If you will do your own research and measure performance you can then add this to the question (assuming there will be noticeable difference) and ask what cause that change in performance.

Comment: I disagree that the answer can be only "yes" or "no". I asked if there were any practical differences I should be aware of when deciding which syntax to use. If the answer is "Yes", then I'm asking for these differences to be listed. And if the answer is "No, there is no practical difference, just use whichever style you find more intuitive", then that would be a useful answer too.

Comment: You ask only "Is there" and "Are there" so users will most likely just give Yes/No answers. Also regarding the Underscore documentation question only the developers of Underscore can answer that and I doubt they roam Stack Overflow. As it stands people can just guess.

Comment: None of the reasons you've given here would explain why the question is closed as "Not Constructive."  If you read the question more carefully, you will see that it's asking for a List of Things.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I doubt anyone would just say "Yes" – they would also specify what the differences are; that's obviously what I'm asking for. The question title is phrased "What are the differences..." not "Are there any differences...".

Comment: @callum my point was just proved. "the two styles are equivalent, and you should pick whichever style suits you". Now what is that if not a plain "Yes"? Sorry, but I'm voting to close again.

Comment: @Robert that's a Yes/No question and since there is no better close reason, "Not Constructive" is the closest thing. As for list of things I really can't see such request anywhere in the question.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd "Now what is that if not a plain 'Yes'?" Actually it's closer to a plain 'No'. Which is useful information on its own, as I explained above. And that doesn't mean the question was a yes/no question, because a plain 'Yes' wouldn't have made any sense (because I asked "What are..." rather than "Are there any...").